# implements and extends a class

Tags: java, using, extends, implements

I would like to know why in Java I can do this

```
    interface Specification{
    double Interest =12.5;
    void deposit(double);
    }

    class Base{
    private String Account;
    public Base(String acct){Account=acct;}
    public void Show(){System.out.print("Account # "+Account);}
    }

    class Child extends Base implements Specification{
    public Child (String acct){super(acct);Show();}
    public void deposit(double cash){System.out.print("Now you have "+cash+" Dollars");}
    }
```

**but I can't do this**

```
    class Child implements Specification extends Base{
    public Child (String acct){super(acct);Show();}
    public void deposit(double cash){System.out.print("Now you have "+cash+" Dollars");}
    }
```

Is there any specific order in Java or rule when using `extends` and `implements` in the same *class*.
I would like somebody to explain me the reasons please.

Answer (score 2):

[Because the Java Language Specification says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1). A normal class declaration follows this syntax

```
NormalClassDeclaration:
    ClassModifiers(opt) class Identifier TypeParameters(opt)
                                               Super(opt) Interfaces(opt) ClassBody
```

where `Super` is

```
Super:
    extends ClassType
```

and `Interfaces` is

```
Interfaces:
    implements InterfaceTypeList
```

---

In my opinion, this makes sense. You want to define what something is before defining what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in java there is specific order first class in extended then you can implement many classes :

```
class Child extends Base implements Specification1,Specification2.. -> valid
```

&

```
class Child implements Specification1,Specification2.. extends Base -> not valid
```